# z3 hangs for ever?

Tags: z3, smt

Consider the following [smt2 file](https://github.com/ramanuj1729/klee-z3/blob/master/z3Input_2) generated with the help of Klee.

I am trying to evaluate it using z3. However, z3 hangs forever. Specifically, when the formula is UNSAT, z3 runs for ever and does not produce any result.

1. Is formula size is big?
2. Is there any issue while using logic theory AUFBV?

May I get some suggestions to improve the z3 performance.

Each assert statement having some common subexpression. Is it possible to improve the z3 performance by solving subexpression separately?

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be impossible to answer as the SMT-lib file you've linked is undecipherable for a non-KLEE user. I recommend asking KLEE folks directly using your original program that gave rise to this. Failing that, try to reduce the SMT2Lib to a minimum and see if you can at least hand-annotate to see what it's trying to do.

Regarding your question for common subexpressions: You have to experiment to find out. But the way most such solvers are constructed, they /will/ discover common subexpressions themselves and reuse lemmas about them automatically as they convert your input to an internal representation. So, it'd surprise me if it helped in any significant way to do this by hand; unless the input is really massive. (The example you linked isn't really that big so I doubt that's an issue.)

Comment: There is no issue with Klee. I am not able to get an idea that if I give this file to z3 as input then it fails and hags for ever.  Note that formula is unsat but z3 hangs. If I modify some some conditiont o make it sat then z3 also reports sat and produce a model also.

Comment: Maybe try some other solver? CVC4, MathSAT, Yices? Do any of them manage to solve it? It could just be too difficult to prove.